# Android wear Check if phone app is running

Tags: android, synchronization, wear-os

I have both an Android wear and a phone app where the movile app sends a file to the phone, but I need to check whether the phone app is running (at least in background) because otherwise i wolud lost the file that was sent. I know that I could send a sync message or something like that, but I would prefer to know if there is a "prettier" way of knowing it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not a built-in API for this. If this is a necessary feature, you'd have to go the route you mentioned of "send a sync message or something like that".

However, there are a couple of related aspects to be aware of which might help you:

- If your receiving code extends `WearableListenerService`, the system will start it when new data arrives. There's no need for it to be running already. Details here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events#Listen
- If for some reason it can't be started - or you don't want to use a Service like this - you still won't lose the data. `DataItem`s (and attached assets) sent through the Data API are asynchronous, and will wait until you query for them. There's no need for the receiving app to be running at the time they're sent.